# Finding labels together with ids in html tags using Python

Tags: python, html, regex

I have used selenium to extract the html code of a website, which I have placed in the variable html_code

I would like to extract the labels and the corresponding ids of those html tags.

So far, I have managed to extract the labels alone using

> `var1 = re.findall(r'<label\s*.*>(.+?)<\?label>', html_code)`

My question is: how do I extract the corresponding ids of the html tags together with the labels? What function do I use? Could I use findall, or a combination of other functions for this?

Comment: What is a tag id?

Comment: Upload HTML snippet and explain the expected output.

Comment: It is [ill-advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1040092) to use regex on HTML. What you are trying to do sounds feasible with an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup

Comment: @balder Here is an example of a HTML snippet I would like to process:

    <label id="id_name" for="whichever" class="class_name">LabelName</label>

I need to extract id_name and LabelName together and put them into pandas dataframe

Comment: @WiktorStribizew please refer to my comment above

Comment: @Wondercricket could you refer me to solution in BeautifulSoup that may solve my issue?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you direct me to any solutions in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/gWXgrC, `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, => `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')` -> `l = soup.find('label')` and then `l.text` prints `'LabelName'` and `l["id"]` prints `'id_name'`.

Comment: @Tipo33 I have solved it using xml parsing. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Beautifulsoup to extract the details you need:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r'<label id="id_name" for="whichever" class="class_name">LabelName</label>')
l = soup.find('label')
l.text
# => 'LabelName'
l["id"]
# => 'id_name'
```

With `soup.find('label')`, you get the object, the first node with `label` name in the `soup` object.

The `l.text` gets the text (inner text) value of the node and `l["id"]` gets the `id` attribute value.

Comment: Thanks. It worked really well. Now I have another issue which I need to ask a different question for.

Comment: @Tipo33 If it is closely connected with this page parsing, better ask here in the comments.

Comment: I am looking to document the ids and text of the buttons on the page. Then, for each button, I want to document the id and text of each of the buttons in their submenus. I need them in what may be a graph database style so the crawler can then visit each of these pages.

Comment: @Tipo33 Then you will just need `soup.find_all('button')` or something like that, and then you will be able to iterate over the nodes found, and grab the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

See below. The idea is to "look" at the html using XML parser.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


html = '''<html>
              <label id="id_name1" for="whichever" class="class_name">LabelName1</label>
              <label id="id_name2" for="whichever" class="class_name">LabelName2</label>
          </html>'''

data = []
root = ET.fromstring(html)
for l in root.findall('label'):
    data.append({'id':l.attrib['id'],'text':l.text})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
         id        text
0  id_name1  LabelName1
1  id_name2  LabelName2
```

Comment: I managed to find my solution using Beautiful Soup. I appreciate that you assisted me in this solution. Thanks